# jq merge objects after find in array

Tags: merge, jq

A generated config file (from ls) results in

```
[
  {
    "file": "PDF/College Louise Michèle 402.pdf",
    "rotation": "-90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]
[
  {
    "file": "PDF/College PLUM 4 A.pdf",
    "rotation": "-90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]
[
  {
    "file": "PDF/College RS 4 D.pdf",
    "rotation": "-90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]
[
    {
        "file": "PDF/Q College.pdf",
        "rotation": "90",
        "fiducial": "false"
    }
]
[
    {
        "file": "PDF/Test_q2c.pdf",
        "rotation": "90",
        "fiducial": "true",
        "nopdf": "true"
    }
]
[
    {
        "file": "PDF/Test_q2c.pdf",
        "rotation": "90",
        "fiducial": "true",
        "x":"false"
    }
]
[
  {
    "file": "PDF/Test q2b.pdf",
    "rotation": "90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]
[
  {
    "file": "PDF/Test questionnaires.pdf",
    "rotation": "90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]

[
  {
    "file": "PDF/XCollege Bourail 4 B pdf.pdf",
    "rotation": "-90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]
[
  {
    "file": "PDF/test rotate.pdf",
    "rotation": "90",
    "fiducial": false
  }
]
```

I need to extract each object using filename as key, which is done by

```
jq -r ".[] | select(.file | contains("q2c"))"
```

Unfortunately, there are conflicts and when objects are not unique, I need to merge them.
for instance
obtained answer:

```
{
  "file": "PDF/Test_q2c.pdf",
  "rotation": "90",
  "fiducial": "true",
  "nopdf": "true"
}
{
  "file": "PDF/Test_q2c.pdf",
  "rotation": "90",
  "fiducial": "true",
  "x":"false"
}
```

expected answer

```
{
  "file": "PDF/Test_q2c.pdf",
  "rotation": "90",
  "fiducial": "true",
  "nopdf": "true",
  "x":"false"
}
```

I try with the `.|group_by(.file)[]|add` but get no success...
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relatively smaller input streams, you can "slurp" the objects and combine them into one array using the `add` function and the `-s` command-line option:

```
jq --slurp 'add | map(select(.file | contains("q2c"))) | add'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient solution. Rather than using the -s command-line option, it requires using the -n option:

```
reduce (inputs[] | select(.file|contains("q2c"))) as $in (null;
  .[$in.file] += $in)
| .[]
```

It is space-efficient because it does not require slurping the inputs, and it is time-efficient because (a) it does not use `group_by`, the implementation of which requires sorting, and (b) jq implements key-lookup efficiently.

### Similar formulation using `GROUPS_BY`

As defined here, GROUPS_BY is similar to the built-in filter `group_by` but (a) does not entail a sort; (b) requires that `f` evaluates to a string; and (c) emits a stream of the groups:

```
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f):
  reduce stream as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] ) | .[] ;

GROUPS_BY(inputs[] | select(.file|contains("q2c")); .file)
| add
```